# reset form to initial data in invalid_form and display error in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-generic-views

I have a profile form that shows **email**, **user name** and **first name**. user only allowed to change **first name** field and the others are read only, if user change HTML value in **email** and **username** then submit it, it returns error but fill the fields with invalid value entered. I tried create a new instance of form and render it but it no longer shows the error.
The thing I want is to reset invalid data then display the error.

forms.py

```
class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(
        label='Account email (can not be changed)', max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'email', 'id': 'form-email', 'readonly': 'readonly'}))

    user_name = forms.CharField(
        label='Username', min_length=4, max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'Username', 'id': 'form-username', 'readonly': 'readonly'}))

    first_name = forms.CharField(
        label='First name', min_length=4, max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'Firstname', 'id': 'form-firstname'}))

    class Meta:
        model = UserBase
        fields = ('email', 'user_name', 'first_name',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user_name'].required = True
        self.fields['email'].required = True
    
    def clean_user_name(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['user_name'] 
        if username != self.instance.user_name:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Sorry, you can not change your username')
        return username
    
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if email != self.instance.email:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Sorry, you can not change your email')
        return email
```

views.py

```
class ChangeUserDetail(SuccessMessageMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'accounts/user/default_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:dashboard')
    success_message = "Username changed successfully"
    form_class = UserEditForm


    def get_form(self, form_class=form_class):
        return form_class(instance = self.request.user, **self.get_form_kwargs())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            form = self.form_class(instance=self.request.user)
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super().form_invalid(form)
```

html page

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {% if form.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                {{form.errors}}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <form method="post">
            {%csrf_token%}
            {{form|crispy}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">{{title}}</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few searches I found that I can address my issue by adding **disabled=True** attribute to my fields so if user try to change it database will ignore change and returns the initial value as it said in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#disabled)

```
class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(
        label='Account email (can not be changed)', 
        max_length=200,
        disabled=True, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'email', 'id': 
        'form-email', 'readonly': 'readonly'}))

    user_name = forms.CharField(
        label='Username', 
        disabled=True,
        min_length=4, 
        max_length=50,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'Username', 'id': 
        'form-username', 'readonly': 'readonly'}))
```